# Vim-Latex: forward search doesn't work

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I know people have had this kind of problem before, but I haven't been able to find the solution to my problem anywhere.

First of all, calling `Tex_ForwardSearchLatex()` with `<leader>ls` doesn't work. A command window pops up and disappears (which, I suppose, is the viewer being called from the shell), but nothing happens. If the viewer is not already open, then this doesn't open it.

So I tried a custom function from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2941/how-to-setup-synctex-with-vim-pdflatex-and-an-open-source-pdf-viewer-under-linu/2947#2947), with the same result.

```
function! SyncTexForward()
     let execstr = "silent !okular --unique %:p:r.pdf\\#src:".line(".")."%:p &"
     exec execstr
endfunction
nmap <Leader>f :call SyncTexForward()<CR>
```

This solution is not supposed to work with `\input{}` and `\include{}` subdocuments, but I'm not even there yet. I'm just trying to get the main document to work.

Then I tried a [modified version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83649/40803) of the custom function that supposedly works with subdocuments as well, but again to no avail.

```
function! SyncTexForward()
     let execstr = "silent !okular --unique %:p:r.pdf\#src:".line(".")."%:p &"
     exec execstr
endfunction
nmap <Leader>f :call SyncTexForward()<CR>
```

I thought it might be a problem with spaces in my file/directory names, but no. I've tried a file called test.tex at root with the same result. SyncTex is enabled and the viewers are on the path. The problem is likely what comes after `\#` (i.e. the crucial part), since `:silent !okular --unique %:p:r.pdf` works as expected.

I'm using Windows 7 and Okular, although I also tried SumatraPDF before, with exactly the same result. Frankly, I don't think the problem is with the viewer. Here's what I have in my `tex.vim`

```
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf' 
let g:Tex_CompileRule_dvi='latex -synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials $*'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf='pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf='okular'
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: The following is for Sumatra, not Okular as OP asked. However, I'm sure the problem for Okular is the same as Sumatra.

I think the problem is most likely with your version of Vim-Latex. I fixed the forward-search problem with Sumatra with this [patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/message/30417715/), as well as support for it [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/search/?q=sumatra).

This patch doesn't seem to be in the newest version of Vim-Latex, nor was the diff file the patch provides (meaning the patch utility did nothing). I had to manually apply the patch to my ftplugin/latex-suite/compile.vim file, but after it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (where a command prompt window will flash) and got forward-search to work by adding the following as the "else" statement to handle all the exceptions on Windows machines. Note, the patch had almost worked, except for some `slash...` settings in Vim that may tweak how the Vim function `fnamemodify` shall handle single quotes.

```
let mainfnameRoot = fnamemodify(Tex_GetMainFileName(), ':t:r')
let execString = 'silent! !start '. viewer. ' -reuse-instance -forward-search ' . expand('%:p') . ' ' . line('.') . ' ' . mainfnameRoot . '.pdf'
```

Here goes the complete picture, since the source files have changed slightly.

```
function! Tex_ForwardSearchLaTex()
    ....
    ....
    ....
    if (has('win32'))
        if (viewer =~? '^ *yap\( \|$\)')
            let execString .= Tex_Stringformat('start %s -s %s%s %s', viewer, linenr, sourcefile, mainfnameRoot)
        " SumatraPDF forward search support added by Dieter Castel:
        elseif (viewer =~? "^sumatrapdf")
            " Forward search in sumatra has these arguments (-reuse-instance is optional):
            " SumatraPDF -reuse-instance "pdfPath" -forward-search "texPath" lineNumber
            let execString .= Tex_Stringformat('start %s %s -forward-search %s %s', viewer, target_file, sourcefileFull, linenr)
        """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
        """ THis is the new part
        else
            let mainfnameRoot = fnamemodify(Tex_GetMainFileName(), ':t:r')
            let execString = 'silent! !start '. viewer. ' -reuse-instance -forward-search ' . expand('%:p') . ' ' . line('.') . ' ' . mainfnameRoot . '.pdf'
        endif
    ....
    ....
```