# Vim-Latex: forward search doesn't work well on Windows, featuring significant delay and no visual cues

Tags: vim, vim-latex, sumatrapdf

I managed to let forward search work on my Windows machine with the following specification in my `_vimrc`:

`let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\vim\vim74\gvim\"  -c \":RemoteOpen +\%l \%f\"" '`

The environment: I am running a Gvim installation on a Windows machine, with latest SumatraPDF (removing the Tab feature) and have applied this [patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/vim-latex/mailman/message/30417715/) that aimed at fixing the forward search problem.

However, it only works in a very restrictive way:
When I want to use the `<leader>ls` mapping to trigger a forward jump, I would encounter a 10 seconds delay if I have any SumatraPDF window opened.

Only when there is no SumatraPDF.exe running, may I get a instant forward jump.

Any help that may help me out of this akward situation is well applaused!

Thank you!

Posts that relates to the forward search problem:

[Vim-Latex: forward search doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214643/vim-latex-forward-search-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

Although i can see this is quite old, I've been dealing with this issue for a couple of hours and just got around it. I too have gvim on windows with the vim-latex plugin having trouble with forward search.

The main issue seems to be that the set shellslash isn't playing well with the forward search call to sumatra. I know this setting (shellslash) is recommended for vim-latex on windows but comment it out for forward search to work correctly.

some important vimrc lines:

```
        "set shellslash
        let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat ='pdf'
        let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf ='SumatraPDF'
        let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf='pdflatex -synctex=1 - 
        interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error-style $*'
```

Other notes:

1. make sure to add the sumatrapdf.exe folder to your PATH variable, there's a line in the compiler.vim file:

   ```
   elseif (viewer =~? "^sumatrapdf")
   ```

which seemed to break for me when i included a path in the Tex_ViewRule_pdf variable.

2. the "set shellslash" line doesn't actually remove shellslash if you have it enabled elsewhere in the file, i just included it as a reminder to comment that part out.

Answer (score 0):

The `g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf` variable should only contains the name of the viewer executable. Otherwise, if you set the variable with the full path to the executable, you have to modify the script file: `ftplugin/vim-latex/ftplugin.vim +381`, in which the content of the variable is expected to be started with the string: "sumatrapdf". You can simply remove the `^` from `elseif (viewer =~? "^sumatrapdf")` at line 381 to fulfill that.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I will post my working version that runs well on more than 10 Windows machines in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since the last time that I have updated my Gvim + Sumatra settings. I will post the complete set of settings that I consider as relevant.

In my view, specifying the full path along with the viewing options is not too bad: the side-effect of doing so is that --- the corresponding settings for backward-search is updated automatically.

- The specific setting for the `g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf` variable.

`let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\vim\vim80\gvim.exe\"  -c \":RemoteOpen +\%l \%f\"" '`

- The full set of settings that I am using for Sumatra + Gvim on a Windows machine.

`" Vim-Latex {{{
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set shellslash
set grepprg=grep\ -nH\ $*
set diffexpr=MyDiff()
function! MyDiff()
    let opt = '-a --binary '
    if &diffopt =~ 'icase' | let opt = opt . '-i ' | endif
    if &diffopt =~ 'iwhite' | let opt = opt . '-b ' | endif
    let arg1 = v:fname_in
    if arg1 =~ ' ' | let arg1 = '"' . arg1 . '"' | endif
    let arg2 = v:fname_new
    if arg2 =~ ' ' | let arg2 = '"' . arg2 . '"' | endif
    let arg3 = v:fname_out
    if arg3 =~ ' ' | let arg3 = '"' . arg3 . '"' | endif
    let eq = ''
    if $VIMRUNTIME =~ ' '
        if &sh =~ '\<cmd'
            let cmd = '""' . $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff"'
            let eq = '"'
        else
            let cmd = substitute($VIMRUNTIME, ' ', '" ', '') . '\diff"'
        endif
    else
        let cmd = $VIMRUNTIME . '\diff'
    endif
    silent execute '!' . cmd . ' ' . opt . arg1 . ' ' . arg2 . ' > ' . arg3 . eq
endfunction
let g:tex_flavor='atex'
let g:Tex_GotoError=0 " Will keep the cursor as is.
"let g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings =
"        \'Underfull'."\n".
"        \'Overfull'."\n".
"        \'specifier changed to'."\n".
"        \'You have requested'."\n".
"        \'Missing number, treated as zero.'."\n".
"        \'There were undefined references'."\n".
"        \'Citation %.%# undefined'."\n".
"        \'Font Warning'
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Pair of settings that handle LaTeX Preview Color settings
let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\vim\vim80\gvim.exe\"  -c \":RemoteOpen +\%l \%f\"" '
" let g:Tex_ViewRule_pdf = 'C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -invert-colors  -reuse-instance -inverse-search "\"C:\vim\vim80\gvim.exe\"  -c \":RemoteOpen +\%l \%f\"" '
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" The following section is no longer relevant, as we no longer use Vim to build
" the LaTeX files.
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'
" Skip these Tex compilation errors.
let g:Tex_IgnoredWarnings =
            \'Underfull'."\n".
            \'Overfull'."\n".
            \'specifier changed to'."\n".
            \'You have requested'."\n".
            \'Missing number, treated as zero.'."\n".
            \'There were undefined references'."\n".
            \'Citation %.%# undefined'."\n".
            \'Float too large'."\n".
            \'Package natbib Warning: Empty'."\n".
            \'LaTeX Font Warning'
let g:Tex_IgnoreLevel = 10
" }}}`